# Quick_reply and button postback dynamically handle in messenger bot

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger

How to dynamically handle quick_reply and button postback in facebook messengr bot, suppose i want to show 10 items in **generic elements** So when retrive 10 items in database ,they provide id and details info. So when anyone press any element how to extract the id and how switch statement run.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to do, and I assume that you have 10 elements that have the same text on their buttons, like "choose", and they're postback-type.
And you want to know from which element the "Choose" press came from.

There's a workaround I've managed to do which is inserting spaces to identify the elements buttons, like:

First Element - "Choose"
Second Element - " Choose"
Third Element  - "Choose "
Fourth Element - " Choose "
etc...

I think it's the only way, and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Passed a while since this question has been asked. As of now I was trying to figure out the same thing and this is what I found: https://github.com/Charca/bootbot/issues/10

With this library (the best one for facebook bots in my opinion) you can set a listener for the global postback event and then apply a regex on every one of them in order to get the ID (or information) you need on the single element.

Hope this helps :)